Error loading WASM module: [TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="go" error: module is not an object or function]
Hey guys i stuck on try to pass connection from nodejs to wasm. i successfully deploy it using "node server.js" it open on localhost port 8080. but when i want to test the result
this is the server.js
const net = require('net');
const { WASI } = require('wasi');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = net.createServer(socket => {
    console.log('Client connected');
    const wasi = new WASI({
        args: [],
        env: {},
        preopens: {
            '/dev': '/dev',
            '/tmp': '/tmp',
            '/etc': '/etc',
            '/var': '/var',
        },
        preview1: true,
        version: 'preview1',
    });

    const wasmFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './forwarder.wasm');
    const wasmModuleBuffer = fs.readFileSync(wasmFilePath);
    const goImports = { wasi_snapshot_preview1: wasi.wasiImport };

    WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmModuleBuffer, goImports).then(({ instance }) => {
        const { handleSocket } = instance.exports;
        handleSocket(socket._handle.fd); // Passing socket file descriptor to Go
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error('Error loading WASM module:', err);
    });
});

server.listen(8080, 'localhost', () => {
    console.log('Server listening on localhost:8080');
});

and here the golang code is build into wasm
// go_module.go

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "syscall/js"
)

func handleSocket(this js.Value, inputs []js.Value) interface{} {
    // Convert the file descriptor to a net.File type
    fd := inputs[0].Int()
    file := os.NewFile(uintptr(fd), strconv.Itoa(fd))
    // Convert the net.File to a net.Listener
    listener, err := net.FileListener(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating listener:", err)
        return nil
    }
    defer listener.Close()

    fmt.Println("Waiting for incoming connections...")
    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting connection:", err)
            return nil
        }
        defer conn.Close()
        
        go conn.Write([]byte(" HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nOK"))

        fmt.Println("Received connection from:", conn.RemoteAddr())
        // Handle the connection...
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{}, 0)
    js.Global().Set("handleSocket", js.FuncOf(handleSocket))
    <-c
}

when i tried using "curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080" it returned
Error loading WASM module: [TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="go" error: module is not an object or function]

well i dont even know where to fix this code
